# use variable in next function (Google Sheet Queries)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, global-variables

I have a function that defines a variable and I would like to use the value in the next function.  Each function has it's own query.  I think I either need to combine the queries into one function, of which I don't know how to do or setup a global variable with the first query so it can be referenced in the second function.

I've been reading that global variables and they say they're not a good practice.  Can someone help me with how to reuse a variable from one function to the next or combine the two queries else another JS method I should consider?

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(queryValue1);
function queryValue1 () {
var query2 = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=A2:A17&key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdFNhSzNQUFd3b1ZfRHgtQURINFpzeGc&gid=9');
query2.send(function (response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query2: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    var data1 = response.getDataTable();

    // fetch the data from range cell (row, column) into the span "bx"
    for (var z = 0; z <= 15; z++) {
    document.getElementById('a' + (z + 22)).innerHTML = data1.getValue(z, 0);
}
});
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(queryValue3);
function queryValue3 () {
var query3 = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=B2:B17&key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdFNhSzNQUFd3b1ZfRHgtQURINFpzeGc&gid=10');
query3.send(function (response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query3: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
var data3 = response.getDataTable();
var m1 = data3.getValue(0, 0);
var red22 = "<span style='color:#ff0000' ";
var yellow22 = "<span style='color:#FF9900' ";
var green22 = "<span style='color:#009900' ";
if (m1 <= 70)
{
m1 = red22;
}
else if (71 === m1 && m1 <= 89)
{
m1 = yellow22;
}
else if (m1 >=90)
{
m1 = green22;
}
console.log ("m1= " + m1)
var m1 = (m1 + a22 + "</span>");
console.log ("m1= " + m1)
});
}
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, your making two essentially parallel asynchronous network calls (the `Query.send()` calls). There's no telling which one is going to return first (or if one will fail), so relying in one callback on data from the other is unreliable and a bad idea, no matter whether you use a global variable or something else.

I think you probably just want to chain the two asynchronous calls, so try something of this shape:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(queryValue1);
function queryValue1 () {
  var query2 = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=A2:A17&key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdFNhSzNQUFd3b1ZfRHgtQURINFpzeGc&gid=9');
  query2.send(function (response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query2: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    // Get the data you want to pass to query3 here
    // var query3Data = ...
    queryValue3(query3Data);
  });
}

function queryValue3(passedData) {
  var query3 = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=B2:B17&key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdFNhSzNQUFd3b1ZfRHgtQURINFpzeGc&gid=10');
  query3.send(function (response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query3: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    // Do something with passedData here
    // ...
  });
}
```

So don't start the second query until the first one returned.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the first query is just going to hand it's data over to second function here and there I would create my variables using both queries within the second function?

Comment: Correct. You can pass as much or as little of the first query's response to the second function.